# Is '愛したら解放させ' a correct phrase? Is it's meaning clear?

Tags: meaning, translation, japanese-to-english

I think I've read picked up the sentence '愛したら解放させ' somewhere a long time ago. It is supposed to mean 'if you love something then set it free'. Is it a correct sentence?

Comment: We need the context.

Comment: 「解放させ」 would be the continuative form (meaning another clause would come after) meaning "make it/them let it go", which doesn't make sense.  「解放せよ」 would mean "(you) let it go".  Unless this is some sort of set saying that I'm unfamiliar with.